# Windows 8 \boot\bcd corrupt file error

Tags: windows, boot, bcd

I want to install Windows 8.

I already had Ubuntu and I deleted its partition. Now I can't install Windows 8 and get an error regarding file `\boot\bcd` being corrupt. I have no partitions now, so no Windows or Ubuntu.

I can't create a drive partition either. I tried solving it with bootsect.exe and a Windows Repair DVD but with no luck. Where can I put the BCD if I have no partitions and can't create one?

How can I fix the BCD/bootmgr and install Windows again?

Comment: I assume you have a Win8 DVD available. Try using `diskpart` from the Recovery Environment to `select` the `disk` and `clean` it. If that doesn't work try GParted from a Ubuntu LiveCD to clean the disk completely, then boot from the Win8 DVD and see if you can install.

Comment: I tried this and it worked.thanks!!the only problem is that the usb i was booting windows 8 from, stucked in repair menu, even if i have solved the problem..i never imagined this could ever happen:S

Answer (score -1):

I don't know whether you have solved your problem yet with the previous answer, however I run 3 home built PCs, one runs Windows 7 which I don't have any problems with and use as my main machine for the last 2-3 years, an older machine triple boots into either Windows Me (for older games only and disconnected from internet), Windows XP (for older programmes that are incompatible with either Windows 7 or 8) and Ubuntu 12.04 via Ubuntu's GRUB menu.

I made up my latest machine – an AMD six core – in December 2011 and had great trouble installing Windows 7 which I put down to bad motherboard SATA drivers, I had no trouble installing an earlier version of Ubuntu and did eventually manage to install Windows 7 on a second disc (on port 1 –  Ubuntu being on port 0), however after installation I kept getting disk errors on choosing 7 from GRUB and on the occasions it did boot it would occasionally freeze.

I left matters in abeyance for many months as I wasn't relying on this Windows insatallation until last week when it did boot into Windows 7 and I managed to upgrade it to Windows 8 without any problems until again I got disk errors when I either booted into it via GRUB or by using the motherboard boot option.

However this time it told me that there was a BCD file problem – a message I hadn't seen before. Booting into Linux and examining the Windows 8 system reserved partition, I then found an earlier version of the windows BCD file in the Windows 7 backup file under `Windows/Panther` directory, so I suggest that you use a Linux Ubuntu disk that you can boot from and examine your Windows partitions and replace your BCD file or recreate it using other answers from your Windows 8 disk.